# Convergence of sequence conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Which of the following conditions implies(imply) the convergence of a sequence $\{x_n\} $ of real numbers?(1)given ε>0 there exists a n $n_0$∈N such that for all $n\ge n_0 ,|x_{n+1}-x_n$|<ε

(2)given ε>0 there exists an $n_0$∈N such that for all $n\ge n_0, ~1/(n+1)^2|x_{n+1}-x_n$|<ε

(3)given ε>0 there exists an $n_0$∈N such that for all $n\ge n_0, ~(n+1)^2|x_{n+1}-x_n$|<ε

(4) given ε>0 there exists an $n_0$∈N such that for all n,m with  $m>n\ge n_0, ~|x_{m}-x_n$|<ε

I know, 4-th option is the Cauchy sequence condition, which force sequence convergent, but about the others, what we can tell

Comment: For (1), think about the sequence of partial sums of the harmonic sequence $\{1/n\}$. For (2), think about the sequence of alternating $0$s and $1$s.

Comment: In $(3)$ there seems to be an extra |.

Comment: So, 3 and 4 will be the correct options?

Comment: This looks similar to the proof of the Banach fixed point theorem. If the sum of all of the $|x_n - x_{n-1}|$’s is finite, that should be important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (3), note that
if $\sum a_n$ converges
and $a_n \ge 0$
then
$|x_{n+1}-x_n|
\lt a_n \epsilon$
implies that
$x_n$ converges.

Let
$A = \sum a_n$.

This follows from,
if $n > m$,

$\begin{array}\\
|x_n-x_m|
&=|\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}(x_{j+1}-x_j)|\\
&\le\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}|x_{j+1}-x_j|\\
&\le\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}|x_{j+1}-x_j|\\
&\le\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}a_n\epsilon\\
&\le A\epsilon\\
\end{array}
$

This shows that
$x_n$ converges.

Now apply this to
$a_n = \dfrac1{n^2}$.